# Find coordinates by angle and start point

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

How can i find coordinate of point "C", when i know only:

1) Distance from "A" to "B";

2) Angle

3) Start point

In JS that look's like:

```
let A = {x: 50, y: 30},
    B = {x: 50, y: 80},
    C = {x: null, y: null};
let angle = 345;

let distanceBetweenAB = (B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y);

C = ?
```

Detailed in the picture:

[image: PICTURE with description]

Comment: What do you mean with `a = 345*`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @Bob__ 345* - it is degrees

Comment: In your drawing, a seems to be the measure of an inner angle of a triangle. 345 degrees seems a bit too much. It's the heading of AC relative to some coordinate system, a random value or a typo for 34.5?

Comment: @High Performance Mark sorry, that common question in various programming languages. Now i write it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Find the direction vector from `A` to `B`, rotate it by 90°, and scale:

```
dir = B - A
dirOrth = (-dir.y, dir.x)
C = B + tan(a) * dirOrth
```

If you are not familiar with vectors, just do everything component-wise (i.e. separately for the x/y components).

Comment: Thank. Direction from A to B, that can be write like:
 distanceBetweenAB = (B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y) ?

Comment: It is supposed to be a vector: `dir = (B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y)`.

Answer (score 0):

The x coordinate of C will be same as B i.e. 80.
Using tan(a) you can find distance BC. 
tan(a) = BC/AB  => BC = 30 tan(a).
Then using distance formula on points B and C you can also find y coordinate of point C.

Comment: Thank's, how to find distance between BC, i don't now:

distanceBC = tan(angle) ?